# The trigger('change') function not work in popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Suppose a text field and a button that after click on the button a popup window that contains a table shown and user by click on a row the value of text field set and popup window close.

**Problem:**
In main window not fired change event, I try to trigger this event by jQuery after setting text in popup window but in main window this event is not fired:

```
$('#' + "{{ target_input }}" + '-text', window.opener.document).val(name);
$('#' + "{{ target_input }}" + '-text', window.opener.document).trigger('change');
```

Comment: whether both these elements are from the same domain

Comment: yes, text field and button on the main window and choice items on the popup window.

Comment: Do you really have an element with ID `{{ target_input }}-text`? That seems rather unusual. I assume `{{ target_input }}` is part of some template system... which might not get resolved?

Comment: I using Django-Template system and these lines is server side scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved by using **setInterval** function.

```
setInterval(check, 500);
```

Comment: How did this solve your problem?  What is the value of `check`?  Is that the change event handler?

Comment: `check` is a function that running at every 500 mili second.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix a similar problem by using the following code:

`window.opener.$(<selector of element>).trigger('change');`

I am not sure why triggering the event doesn't work the same way as setting the value.

Comment: Probably because of the way jQuery works in regards to storing data against elements. Since they're two separate documents, you're working with two separate stores of event/data information in jQuery; it can find the element because it's simple DOM querying - and set its property because it's just a property - but jQuery in the popup window doesn't have access to any of jQuery's stored event information for elements in the main window.